# How to insert .p7s byte array into PDF with iText7?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, itext7

I am trying to insert a .p7s byte array info to signature field, I follow this image below:

[image: PDF Document Structure Image]

**My steps:**

**Prepare Signature Container**

the original PDF is "tmp/example.pdf" and the output of this part is "results/prepared.pdf"

```
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader("tmp/example.pdf"), new FileStream("results/prepared.pdf", FileMode.Create), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
signer.SetFieldName("Signature1");

PdfDocument _pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("tmp/example.pdf"));

PdfSignatureAppearance sigAppearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
sigAppearance
    .SetPageRect(new Rectangle(144, 144, 200, 100))
    .SetPageNumber(1)
    .SetContact("This is contact")
    .SetReason("This is reason")
    .SetLocation("This is location")
    .SetSignatureCreator("This is signature creator");

MyExternalSignatureContainer _container = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached, _chain);

IExternalSignatureContainer container = _container; 
signer.SignExternalContainer(container, 8192);
byte[] _sb = _container.Signed_Bytes;
```

**My External Signature Container Class**

```
public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
{
    iText.Signatures.PdfPKCS7 _sgn = new iText.Signatures.PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);
    byte[] _hash = iText.Signatures.DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, "SHA256");
    byte[] _sh = _sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(_hash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
        null, null);

    Signed_Bytes = _sh;

    return new byte[0]; ;
}
```

until this part, everything goes fine, I got "results/prepared.pdf" 
hash and sent to external signing service and got the .p7s

now I want to insert the .p7s byte[] into the signature value part of a PDF structure based on the image above.

I try to get the `PdfDictionay`'s `ByteRange` info of "results/prepared.pdf" using code below, I expect to get injected .p7s to  signature container of "results/prepared.pdf" at "results/injected.pdf"

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("results/prepared.pdf"), new PdfWriter("results/injected.pdf").SetSmartMode(true));

 SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
PdfSignature signature = signatureUtil.GetSignature("Signature1");

PdfDictionary _pd = signatureUtil.GetSignatureDictionary("Signature1");
```

Now I got the result of "_pd" as follow:

```
{<</ByteRange [0 107457 123843 2688 ] /ContactInfo This is contact /Contents
```

**my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong) is I should put .p7s byte array to 107457 as start position.**

**Try to inject .p7s into existing signature container**

I try to make `paddedSig` array below and copy .p7s to it:

```
byte[] _p7s = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("tmp/example.p7s");
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
System.Array.Copy(_p7s, 0, paddedSig, 0, _p7s.Length);
```

and then try to put paddedSig to PdfDictionary as below:

```
PdfDictionary _pd = signatureUtil.GetSignatureDictionary("Signature1");
pd.Put(PdfName.Contents, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));

pdfDocument.Close();
```

a new PDF named "results/injected.pdf" generated, but:

> Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data.
>   Support Information: SigDict /Contents illegal data

What did I miss? .. How to inject .p7s into prepared signature container?

**To response Mkl's post:**

What I don't understand is how to embed returning PKCS#7 byte into the pdf..
assume byte[] _p7s is the result from API_CALL

```
byte[] _p7s = API_CALL;
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
System.Array.Copy(_p7s, 0, paddedSig, 0, _p7s.Length);
```

and then try to put paddedSig to PdfDictionary as below:

```
PdfDictionary _pd = signatureUtil.GetSignatureDictionary("Signature1");
pd.Put(PdfName.Contents, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));

pdfDocument.Close();
```

the result is:

**Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data.
Support Information: SigDict /Contents illegal data**

**Trying with .p7s file**

I have an example.p7s file, I try to embed using the code provided as below:

```
 byte[] _p7s = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("tmp/example.p7s");

 private static void Embed_P7S(Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] _chain, byte[] _p7s)
    {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("results/example-prepared.pdf"));
        Stream output = new FileStream("results/example-prepared-signed.pdf", FileMode.Create);

        ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer container2 = new ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer(_p7s);

        PdfSigner.SignDeferred(document, "Signature1", output, container2);
    }
}


internal class ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer :IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    public ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer(byte[] signature)
    {
        Signature = signature;
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        return Signature;
    }

    public byte[] Signature;
}
```

result:

example-prepared-signed.pdf no certificate shown (this is like the original pdf)
but the size bigger than the original pdf

original.pdf is 105KB
example-prepared is 124KB
example-prepared-signed is 121KB

[this is the .p7s](http://apps.primteksolusindo.com/example.p7s)

Comment: *"What I don't understand is how to embed returning PKCS#7 byte into the pdf.. assume byte[] _p7s is the result from API_CALL"* - Don't do it manually, let iText do it for you, simply return the signature from the appropriate `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not have to split the signing process like you do. I've seen a lot of questions in which the developers want to do this, but strictly speaking it is not necessary (well, under the hood iText still will first create a prepared PDF and later inject the signature container, but it can be kept under the hood).

Splitting the process only is necessary if the external signing service takes very long to create the signature and you cannot keep the PDF in memory for that time.

I'll look into both variants here.

#### Single pass signing

If your external signing service returns the result (a full PKCS#7 signature container) fast enough, you should use this approach. The base code starts similar to yours:

```
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader("example.pdf"), new FileStream("example-signed.pdf", FileMode.Create), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
signer.SetFieldName("Signature1");

PdfSignatureAppearance sigAppearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
sigAppearance
    .SetPageRect(new Rectangle(144, 144, 200, 100))
    .SetPageNumber(1)
    .SetContact("This is contact")
    .SetReason("This is reason")
    .SetLocation("This is location")
    .SetSignatureCreator("This is signature creator");

ExternalServiceSignatureContainer container = new ExternalServiceSignatureContainer();

signer.SignExternalContainer(container, 8192);
```

The difference to your code is in the `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation:

```
public class ExternalServiceSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
        signDic.Put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
        signDic.Put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        // Call your external signing service to create a CMS signature container
        // for the data in the InputStream and return that signature container

        [... see below ...]
    }
}
```

Depending on your API to access that external signing service the implementation of `Sign` differs. In each case I assume the API_CALL to return the result PKCS#7 signature container as byte array:

- You may either be able to directly call it with the stream

  ```
  return YOUR_SIGNING_API_CALL_FOR_STREAM(data);
  ```
- or with a byte[] generated from the stream contents

  ```
  return YOUR_SIGNING_API_CALL_FOR_ARRAY(StreamUtil.InputStreamToArray(data));
  ```

  as parameter,
- or you may first have to hash the data yourself (e.g. as follows) and send your hash to the service.

  ```
  byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
  return YOUR_SIGNING_API_CALL_FOR_HASH(hash)
  ```

The output of the `signer` already is the finalized, signed PDF.

This essentially is the case already discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168641/1729265).

#### Two pass signing

If your external signing service does not return the result (a full PKCS#7 signature container) fast enough (e.g. in case of batch signature APIs or in case of services waiting for some confirmation for a long time if necessary) or if on your side you implement the part before calling the signing service and the part thereafter in separate programs (some people indeed do so), you can use this approach.

Again the base code starts similar to yours:

```
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader("example.pdf"), new FileStream("example-prepared.pdf", FileMode.Create), new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
signer.SetFieldName("Signature1");

PdfSignatureAppearance sigAppearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();
sigAppearance
    .SetPageRect(new Rectangle(144, 144, 200, 100))
    .SetPageNumber(1)
    .SetContact("This is contact")
    .SetReason("This is reason")
    .SetLocation("This is location")
    .SetSignatureCreator("This is signature creator");

ExternalEmptySignatureContainer container = new ExternalEmptySignatureContainer();

signer.SignExternalContainer(container, 8192);

byte[] dataToSign = container.Data;
```

The `ExternalEmptySignatureContainer` now only provides the data to sign by the signing service later, it does not inject a signature container yet

```
public class ExternalEmptySignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
        signDic.Put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
        signDic.Put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        // Store the data to sign and return an empty array

        [... see below ...]

        return new byte[0];
    }

    public byte[] Data;
}
```

Depending on your API to access that external signing service the implementation of `Sign` differs.

- If your signing API expects the original data for signing, use a byte[] generated from the stream contents

  ```
  Data = StreamUtil.InputStreamToArray(data);
  ```
- If your signing API expects the a hash of the original data for signing, calculate it like this from the stream contents

  ```
  Data = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
  ```

The output of the `signer` is the intermediary, prepared PDF.

The next step is to call the signing service and to retrieve the PKCS#7 signature container:

```
byte[] signature = YOUR_SIGNING_API_CALL(dataToSign);
```

Finally you inject that signature container into the prepared PDF:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("example-prepared.pdf"));
using (Stream output = new FileStream("example-prepared-signed.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer container2 = new ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer(signature);

    PdfSigner.SignDeferred(document, "Signature1", output, container2);
}
```

The `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation merely injects the signature bytes:

```
public class ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    public ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer(byte[] signature)
    {
        Signature = signature;
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        return Signature;
    }

    public byte[] Signature;
}
```

The output is the finalized, signed PDF.

Comment: Thank you very much Mkl, I am really waiting for this answer.. but what I don't understand is how to embed or inject returning PKCS#7 into the Pdf?..

Comment: *"but what I don't understand is how to embed or inject returning PKCS#7 into the Pdf?"* - in the single pass variant iText does it for you in `signer.SignExternalContainer`, it injects what you return from `ExternalServiceSignatureContainer.Sign`. In the two pass variant iText does it for you in `PdfSigner.SignDeferred`, it injects what you return from `ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer.Sign`.

Comment: two pass variant not working.. produced pdf  "example-prepared-signed.pdf" no certificate shown (it's like the original pdf)

Comment: I tested it here and it did work. Please share your "example-prepared-signed.pdf" for analysis.

Comment: Your `example-prepared-signed.pdf` is cut off, a part is missing (the prepared and the prepared-signed documents must have the same length, otherwise you know something unexpected happened). Was one of those files probably open in some other program?

Comment: By the way, there also is an error in the signed hash.

Comment: Mkl.. it solved now .. I forgot to close the stream..
but now .. it shows Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed

Comment: The hash is wrong. But looking at your code the reason is obvious, in `Program.Main` you don't inject a PKCS#7 signature container signing the `_data_to_sign` but instead some PKCS#7 signature container you loaded from some external file. Thus, the hash in the signature does not match the hash of the signed bytes in the PDF.

Comment: so you mean, I have to  ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer container2 = new ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer(_data_to_sign);

Comment: if I use  _data_to_sign in ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer .. the result will be the same like example-prepared.pdf

Comment: No. You have to create a PKCS#7 signature container signing `_data_to_sign` and use that as argument of `ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer`. You cannot simply take some arbitrary signature container, inject it into a newly prepared PDF, and expect that arbitrary signature to match.

Comment: Do you mean, I have to create a p7s file in ExternalEmptySignatureContainer Sign?
the PKCS7 actually returns from API_CALL, CMIIW..
so for this simulation.. I create a dummy p7s file in Sign event?

Comment: *"Do you mean, I have to create a p7s file in ExternalEmptySignatureContainer Sign?"* - No. You can do it in main. Between `byte[] _data_to_sign = Prepare_Pdf();` and `Embed_P7S(_p7s);` do `_p7s = API_CALL(data_to_sign);`

Comment: so the API_CALL will returns _p7s byte[] and I should able to use it to inject the Pdf..
Ok..
in between PreparePdf() and Embed_P7S() .. I will create a dummy p7s using local private key and try to pass it and pass returning to inject..

will try this now.. get back to you soob

Comment: great job!.. you are very helpful and safe my time.. have a great and safe weekend