# itext7: deferred signing not producing a valid signed pdf

Tags: certificate, itext, .net-5

I'm trying to use itext7 to sign a pdf by getting the signature from an external entity. I must be missing something because the deferred pdf signing is not valid. Lets start with the code for deferred signing:

```
public byte[] GetDocHashFromPreparedDocToSign(string pathToOriginalPdf, string pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf, List<X509Certificate> certificates) {
    var pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader(pathToOriginalPdf),
                                  new FileStream(pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf, FileMode.Create),
                                  new StampingProperties());
    pdfSigner.SetFieldName(_signatureFieldname);


    var appearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.SetPageRect(new Rectangle(144, 144, 200, 100))
              .SetPageNumber(1)
              .SetCertificate(certificates[0]);

    var container = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(container, 8192);
    



   byte[] sha256SigPrefix = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09,
                                 0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01,
                                 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20 };
    // service needs to receive sha256 prepended
    using var stream = File.OpenRead(pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf);
    var data = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(stream, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);        
    var totalHash = new byte[sha256SigPrefix.Length + data.Length];
    sha256SigPrefix.CopyTo(totalHash, 0);
    data.CopyTo(totalHash, sha256SigPrefix.Length);
    return totalHash;
}
```

The method received the path to the original pdf, the path to the temporary pdf that will contain the placeholder for the signature and a list of X509Certificate that is retrieved from the original service. After reserving the space for the signature, the method calculates the file's hash and prepends it with the sha256 prefix (required by the service that will sign the document).

This information is sent to the service which will return the signature. When the signature is retrieved, the following method is called for filling the signature placeholder with the real signature:

```
public void SignPreparedToBeSignedDoc(string pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf, string pathToSignedFile, byte[] signature) {
    var document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf));
    using var writer = new FileStream(pathToSignedFile, FileMode.Create);

    var container = new ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer(signature);
    PdfSigner.SignDeferred(document, _signatureFieldname, writer, container);
}
```

**EDIT**: based on @mkl comment, I've fixed the signing part:
And here's the ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer:

```
internal class ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer {
    private readonly byte[] _signature;

    public ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer(byte[] signature) {
        _signature = signature;
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data){
        var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, _certificates.ToArray(), "SHA256", false);
        sgn.SetExternalDigest(_signature, null, "RSA");
        return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7();

    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }
}
```

Even though the code runs without errors, opening the pdf in adobe shows the following error:

[image: Error while signing pdf]

**EDIT**: after fixing the signing code, now the error is different: it will show the signature info but it will say that the file has been changed or is corrupted.

At this point, it seems like the temporary pdf is being generated correctly, but I'm probably missing something...any clues on how I might debug this issue?

Thanks

**EDIT**: in response to the comments to the solution presented by @mkl, I've tried to update the code. I had a couple more minutes to play with this today and I've tried to follow the presented guidelines, but I'm clearly still missing something.

Before showing the new code, I'd just like to point out that the previous updated version (that whas using 2 `IExternalSignatureContainer` instances) seemed to be working correctly. ie, opening the signed pdf on adobe would only show me the yellow warning saying that there was something wrong with the signature:

[image: Signed pdf with original code]

Since the doc is being used with a test chain, it seems like the signing worked ok (though I might be completely wrong).

So, in order to fix the incorrect usage of the container, I've rewritten the code for the `IExternalSignatureContainer`'s `Sign` methods. Here's the code I've got for the one that prepares the document hash that is going to be sent to the server:

```
public override byte[] Sign(Stream data) {
// create PCKS7 for getting attributes
var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, _certificates.ToArray(), DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, false);
// get document hash
DocumentDigest = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
// get attributes
var docBytesHash = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(DocumentDigest, 
                                PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, 
                                null, 
                                null);
 //prepend sha256 prefix
 var totalHash = new byte[_sha256SigPrefix.Length + docBytesHash.Length];
 _sha256SigPrefix.CopyTo(totalHash, 0);
 docBytesHash.CopyTo(totalHash, _sha256SigPrefix.Length);
 DataToSend = totalHash;
 return new byte[0];
}
```

Since I must call the `GetEncodedPKCS7` method with the same parameters that were passed to `GetAuthenticatedAttributes`, I'm also saving the document hash obtained through the `Digest` method. `DataToSend` will be sent to the server so that it can return the signature for that hash.

And here's the code for the other `IExternalSignatureContainer` that will be called for the deferred signing (`PdfSigner.SignDeferred`):

```
public byte[] Sign(Stream data) {
    // create CMS      
    var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, _certificates.ToArray(), DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, false);
    // set the signature bytes
    sgn.SetExternalDigest(_signature, null, "RSA");
    // call GetEncoded with the same parameters as the original GetAuthenticatedAtt...
    //_documentHash == DocumentDigest previous sample
    var encodedSig = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(_documentHash,
                                         PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                                         null,
                                         null,
                                         null);

    return encodedSig;
}
```

Unfortunately, I must be missing something (or lots of things):

[image: Error with signature]

Did I completely missed your point?

**EDIT**: Once again, following @mkl's lead, I was able to make it work. Like he said, you need to hash the `GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` value:

```
public override byte[] Sign(Stream data) {
// create PCKS7 for getting attributes
var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, _certificates.ToArray(), DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, false);
// get document hash
DocumentDigest = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
// get attributes
var docBytes = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(DocumentDigest, 
                                PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, 
                                null, 
                                null);
// hash dochBytes 
using var hashMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(docBytes, false);
var docBytesHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(hashMemoryStream, 
                                            DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
 //prepend sha256 prefix
 var totalHash = new byte[_sha256SigPrefix.Length + docBytesHash.Length];
 _sha256SigPrefix.CopyTo(totalHash, 0);
 docBytesHash.CopyTo(totalHash, _sha256SigPrefix.Length);
 DataToSend = totalHash;
 return new byte[0];
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You hash the complete prepared PDF. This is wrong, you have to hash the prepared PDF except the placeholder for the signature container eventually to inject. Furthermore, the `byte[] _signature` you eventually inject appears not to be a proper CMS signature container; either it is a broken container or not a container at all.

Comment: Yep, _signature was not correct...I'm not following the hashing part...pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf is the path to the pdf which has the signature place holder. is this wrong? thanks

Comment: I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: ok. I'll update the _signature part of the existing post :)

Comment: Ok. But there is yet another error... I'll try to explain in my answer, too.

Comment: thanks!! I really appreciate it.....

Comment: I'll complete my answer later, explaining how better to fare if your service returns a naked signature bytes value instead of a CMS signature container.

Comment: *"Before showing the new code, I'd just like to point out that the previous updated version (that whas using 2 IExternalSignatureContainer instances) seemed to be working correctly. ie, opening the signed pdf on adobe would only show me the yellow warning saying that there was something wrong with the signature:"* - please share an example PDF signed like that. It is just possible that that state of your code *did create valid signatures* of a kind which validators with **low security requirements** (e.g. an Adobe Reader) would accept.

Comment: Hello again. Here's a link for a document that seems to be working fine https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4560zevusue92m/doc1_signed.pdf?dl=0. Btw, if there's any updated documentation for itext for net please let me know... Thanks again.

Comment: *"So, in order to fix the incorrect usage of the container, I've rewritten the code"* - Please share an example PDF like that, too; at first glance the code looks ok.

Comment: Hello again. Here's an example of the same document signed with the latest code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfsdy862h4m9zk7/doc1_signed1.pdf?dl=0. Btw, have you found anything wrong with the pdf signed with the "incorrect" code? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I had a look at your [doc1_signed.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4560zevusue92m/doc1_signed.pdf?dl=0) - yes, it is valid as a generic signature. But the CMS signature container structurally is extremely simple; many profiles (e.g. European PAdES signatures) require extra attributes which in turn require a more complex structure which require you to create the container in two steps. Thus, if all you require is that people see "valid" in Adobe Reader (which you'd get for a certificate from an AATL or EUTL CA), you can use that structure. For more serious use cases you cannot.

Comment: Ah, concerning [doc1_signed1.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfsdy862h4m9zk7/doc1_signed1.pdf?dl=0) - analyzing it the problem becomes clear: you have to hash the result of `sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` and then use that hash value in the following step. Yes, there are two hashing steps.

Comment: that was it: adding the hash to the hash returned from the <code>GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes</code> did it! Now, let's see how to timestamp the signature :)

PS: I'll update the code and leave your answer as correct. If you ever visit Madeira, give me a ping and I'll buy you  a beer :) Thanks again!!!

Comment: Great we could get that resolved! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two apparent issues, you hash the wrong data and you inject a wrong type of signature:

#### Hashing the wrong data

You calculate the hash to be signed like this:

```c#
using var stream = File.OpenRead(pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf);
var data = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(stream, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
```

This is not correct.

A signed PDF essentially has this structure (read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for more details):

[image: sketch]

*(By the way, the sketch is not 100% correct as the angled bracket delimiters '<' and '>' around the signature value must also not be hashed.)*

Your prepared PDF at `pathToPreparedToBeSignedPdf` has the same structure, merely the "signature value" is not yet an actual *signature* value but instead a placeholder of 8192 hex-encoded zero bytes (8192 because that's the number you gave in `pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer`).

As you can see in the sketch, though, the signature value (or in your case, the placeholder) must not be hashed for signing.

The easiest way to retrieve the prepared PDF except the placeholder is inside the `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation you use for preparing the PDF as its `Sign` method as parameter gets a stream containing exactly that. So instead of the `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer` use something like the `ExternalEmptySignatureContainer` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61832667/1729265):

```c#
public class ExternalEmptySignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
{
    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
    {
        signDic.Put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
        signDic.Put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
    }

    public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
    {
        // Store the data to sign and return an empty array
        Data = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
        return new byte[0];
    }

    public byte[] Data;
}
```

and after preparing retrieve the `byte[]` from its `Data` member:

```
var container = new ExternalEmptySignatureContainer();
pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(container, 8192);
byte[] hash = container.Data;
```

In your case you may have to prepend the `sha256SigPrefix` to get a complete encoded `DigestInfo` object.

#### Injecting a wrong type of signature

Furthermore, considering your screen shot

[image: screen shot]

you apparently inject a signature of a wrong type. You set a subfilter `PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached` which implies that the signature to embed is a CMS signature container with a single SignerInfo signing the signed bytes of the PDF. The error message indicates, though, that the signature container you embed either is broken or is not a CMS signature container to start with.

#### After your edit: Injecting a signature container with incorrect contents

To fix the previous issue, "Injecting a wrong type of signature", you changed your `ExternalInjectingSignatureContainer` to build a CMS signature container for your signature bytes like this:

```
var sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, _certificates.ToArray(), "SHA256", false);
sgn.SetExternalDigest(_signature, null, "RSA");
return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7();
```

This, unfortunately, uses the `PdfPKCS7` class incorrectly resulting in a CMS signature container with incorrect data.

*(**Correction**: The resulting CMS container is not *incorrect* per se, but it is structurally extremely simply. Nowadays many profiles - e.g. European PAdES - require additional, signed attributes, and to satisfy such profiles you have to fix as described in the following text. If you only need Adobe Reader to show valid, though, the code above suffices for you.)*

To fix you can either indeed build a CMS signature container yourself, using the iText `PdfPKCS7` class or other means (like BouncyCastle or built-in .Net classes), or you can let iText do that for you.

The easiest approach is the latter one. You actually don't need deferred signing here at all, you simply implement `IExternalSignature` so that it calls your remote service:

```
public class RemoteSignature : IExternalSignature
{
    public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message) {
        IDigest messageDigest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest(GetHashAlgorithm());
        byte[] messageHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(messageDigest, message);
        byte[] digestInfo = [... prefix messageHash with sha256SigPrefix ...];
        //
        // Request signature for DigestInfo digestInfo 
        // and return signature bytes
        //
        return CALL_YOUR_SERVICE_FOR_SIGNATURE_OF_HASH(digestInfo);
    } 

    public virtual String GetHashAlgorithm() {
        return "SHA-256";
    } 

    public virtual String GetEncryptionAlgorithm() {
        return "RSA";
    } 
}
```

Now you can simply sign doing

```
var pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader(pathToOriginalPdf),
                              new FileStream(pathToSignedFile, FileMode.Create),
                              new StampingProperties());
pdfSigner.SetFieldName(_signatureFieldname);

var appearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
appearance.SetPageRect(new Rectangle(144, 144, 200, 100))
          .SetPageNumber(1)
          .SetCertificate(certificates[0]);

var signature = new RemoteSignature();
pdfSigner.SignDetached(signature, certificates, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Comment: thanks for the excellent explanation. Unfortunately, I'll have to go through the CMS signature container path because the the call that returns the hash is protected by an SMS code. Btw, if I'm not mistaken, the problem you're seeing in the PdfPKC7 is related with the subfilter specified, right? If I understood you correctly, I've set it up for a single certificate but then I've created one with the full certificate chain...Can you tell me which value to use for the subfilter when passing the certificate chain?

Comment: *"the problem you're seeing in the PdfPKC7 is related with the subfilter specified, right?"* - No. To use a `PdfPKCS7 pkcs7` properly, you have to call `pkcs7.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` with the document hash (without the sha256SigPrefix) to get the signed attributes to be, hash and sign them, set the resulting signature bytes using `pkcs7.SetExternalDigest`, and eventually call `pkcs7.GetEncodedPKCS7` with the same parameters as the original `GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` call.

Comment: It's not working...Do you know if there's any sample out there which shows how to properly use this approach strategy?

Comment: I'll try and look into this. Might take until next week, though.

Comment: @LuisAbreu Ok, I looked over your comment once again. You say you *will have to go through the CMS signature container path because the the call that returns the hash is protected by an SMS code.* That SMS code only is a hindrance if you consider that this might take too long to keep the thread running and waiting for the signature. How separated do you plan the start of signing and the end of it to be? I ask because you must initialize the `PdfPKCS7` object at the start and use it again at the end. Does your design allow holding such an object associated with the signing task?

Comment: @LuisAbreu If not, things get a bit more complicated because you will have to identically instantiate `PdfPKCS7` objects at the start and the end of signing. If, in particular the end of signing occurs during different runs of the same program or in different programs, probably on different servers, you'll have to take care and hold the information required for that identical instantiation somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it will have to be really separated (it will be for a web app). ..will creating 2 instances of PdfPKCS7 produce the expected results? At this point, I'm more interested in understanding if the code I've written is wrong (edit the previous post) because it's not working...