# itext8: migration breaks external signing

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm trying to migrate an existing code base to itext 7 which is responsible for signing pdf files (ti's deferred signing). After migrating to the new apis, the document does get signed, but it's giving an error which says that the document has been modified after signing:

[image]

I guess that I'm probably miscalculating the size reserved for the signing, but I'm not sure on where I'm messing things up. here's my current code:

```
TSAClientBouncyCastle tsaClient = new("https://freetsa.org/tsr");
// crl list for revocation
// userCertificationChain is a IEnumerable<x509> with the certificate chain used for signimng
List<ICrlClient> crlClients = new() {new CrlClientOnline(userCertificatesChain.ToArray())};
// added ocsp client
OcspClientBouncyCastle ocspClient = new(null);
PdfSignerHelper sgn = new PdfSignerHelper(userCertificatesChain.ToArray( ));

PdfSigningManager pdfSigner = new(userCertificatesChain,
                                  sgn,
                                  crlClients: crlClients,
                                  ocspClient: ocspClient,
                                  tsaClient: tsaClient);

HashesForSigning hashInformation = pdfSigner.CreateTemporaryPdfForSigning(
    new SigningInformation(pdfToBeSigned,                                                                                                            
                           temporaryPdf,
                           Reason: "Because yes",
                           Location: "Funchal",
                           Logo: logo));

// signinginformation is a simple record for passing info between objects
```

`CreateTemporaryPdfForSigning` looks like this:

```
public HashesForSigning CreateTemporaryPdfForSigning(SigningInformation signingInformation) {
    StampingProperties properties = new();
    properties.UseAppendMode();
    
    PdfSigner pdfSigner = new(new PdfReader(signingInformation.PathToPdf),
                              new FileStream(signingInformation.PathToIntermediaryPdf, FileMode.Create),
                              properties);
    pdfSigner.SetFieldName(_signatureFieldname);

    SignatureFieldAppearance appearance = new(pdfSigner.GetFieldName());
    if(signingInformation.Logo is null) {
        appearance.SetContent(BuildVisibleInformation(signingInformation.Reason,
                                                      signingInformation.Location));
    }
    else {
        appearance.SetContent(BuildVisibleInformation(signingInformation.Reason,
                                                      signingInformation.Location),
                              signingInformation.Logo);
    }

    appearance.SetFontSize(6f);
    pdfSigner.SetSignatureAppearance(appearance);
    pdfSigner.SetPageNumber(signingInformation.PageNumber)
             .SetPageRect(new Rectangle(10, 750, 150,50));
    
    IList<byte[]>? crlBytesList = GetCrlByteList();
    IList<byte[]>? ocspBytesList = GetOcspBytesList();

    int estimatedSize = EstimateContainerSize(crlBytesList, ocspBytesList);
    Console.WriteLine($"Estimated size: {estimatedSize}");
    PrepareForAmaSigningContainer container = new(_sgn, 
                                                  crlBytesList, 
                                                  ocspBytesList);
    pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(container, estimatedSize); // add size for timestamp in signature

    return new HashesForSigning(container.HashToBeSignedByAma, container.NakedHash);
}
```

The `EstimateContainerSize` method is responsible for calculating the estimated size of the signature. Btw, here's how it's getting calculated:

```
private int EstimateContainerSize(IEnumerable<byte[]>? crlBytesList,
                                  , IEnumerable<byte[]>? ocspBytesList) {
    int estimatedSize = 8192 + //initial base container size
                      ( _ocspClient != null ? 4192 : 0 ) +
                      ( _tsaClient != null  ? 4600 : 0 );
    if(crlBytesList != null) {
        estimatedSize += crlBytesList.Sum(crlBytes => crlBytes.Length + 10);
    }

    if(ocspBytesList != null) {
         estimatedSize += ocspBytesList.Sum(c => c.Length + 10);
    }

    return estimatedSize;
}
```

**EDIT**: as suggested by @mkl, I've updated the code so that the same `PdfPKCS7` instance is used when required. It's encapsulated in a new type which looks like this:

```
public sealed class PdfSignerHelper {
    
    private const string _signaturePolicyUri = "https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/documents/20126/0/POL%2316.PolAssQual_signed_signed.pdf";
    
    private readonly PdfPKCS7 _sgn;

    public PdfSignerHelper(IEnumerable<IX509Certificate> certificates) {
        _sgn = new(null,
                   certificates.ToArray( ),
                   DigestAlgorithms.SHA256,
                   false);
            
        // set signature policy information
        MemoryStream policyIdByteMs = new(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("2.16.620.2.1.2.2"), false);
        byte[]? policyIdByte = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(policyIdByteMs, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
        SignaturePolicyInfo spi = new("2.16.620.2.1.2.2", policyIdByte, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, _signaturePolicyUri);
        _sgn.SetSignaturePolicy(spi);
    }

    public PdfPKCS7 Signer => _sgn;

}
```

This type is injected in several of the other existing types and it's kept on a field named `_sgn` (for instance, you'll see it on the `CreateTemporaryPdfForSigning' method being passed to the constructor of` PrepareForAmaSigningContainer`

`PrepareForAmaSigningContainer` is a simple class which extends the `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer` for creating a "blank" signature:

```
public class PrepareForAmaSigningContainer : ExternalBlankSignatureContainer {
    private static readonly byte[] _sha256SigPrefix = {
                                                          0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09,
                                                          0x60, 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01,
                                                          0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20
                                                      };

    private readonly IEnumerable<byte[]>? _crlBytesCollection;
    private readonly IEnumerable<byte[]>? _ocspBytes;
    private readonly PdfSignerHelper _sgn;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the container
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="certificates">User certficate chain</param>
    /// <param name="crlBytesCollection">Collection of CRL bytes for revocation check</param>
    /// <param name="ocspBytes">Collection od OCSP bytes for revocation</param>
    public PrepareForAmaSigningContainer(PdfSignerHelper sgn,
                                         IEnumerable<byte[]>? crlBytesCollection,
                                         IEnumerable<byte[]>? ocspBytes) : base(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached) {
        _crlBytesCollection = crlBytesCollection;
        _ocspBytes = ocspBytes;
        _sgn = sgn;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the hash that must be send for signing
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] HashToBeSignedByAma { get; private set; } = new byte[0];

    /// <summary>
    /// Original naked hash of the document (used for injecting the signature when it's retrieved from AMA)
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] NakedHash { get; private set; } = new byte[0];

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that will be called during the signing process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">Stream with the doc data that should be used in the hasing process</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override byte[] Sign(Stream data) {
        
        // get hash for document bytes
        NakedHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);

        // get attributes
        byte[]? docBytes = _sgn.Signer.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(NakedHash,
                                                                      PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                                                                      _ocspBytes?.ToList( ),
                                                                      _crlBytesCollection?.ToList( ));
        // hash it again
        using MemoryStream hashMemoryStream = new(docBytes, false);
        byte[]? docBytesHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(hashMemoryStream, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);


        //prepend sha256 prefix
        byte[] totalHash = new byte[_sha256SigPrefix.Length + docBytesHash.Length];
        _sha256SigPrefix.CopyTo(totalHash, 0);
        docBytesHash.CopyTo(totalHash, _sha256SigPrefix.Length);
        HashToBeSignedByAma = totalHash;
        Console.WriteLine($"size hash to be signed ama: {totalHash.Length}");
        return Array.Empty<byte>();
    }
}
```

The returned `HashesForSigning` is then passed to an external service which returns a byte array with the signature that will get appended to the intermediate doc:

```
byte[] signature = GetExternalSignature();

pdfSigner.SignIntermediatePdf(new SignatureInformation(temporaryPdf,
                                                                   finalPdf,
                                                                   signature,
                                                                   hashInformation.NakedHash));
```

And here's the helper method that appends the signature to the intermediate pdf to get the signed pdf:

```
public void SignIntermediatePdf(SignatureInformation signatureInformation) {
    PdfDocument document = new(new PdfReader(signatureInformation.PathToIntermediaryPdf));
    using FileStream writer = new(signatureInformation.pathToSignedPdf, FileMode.Create);

    
    IList<byte[]>? crlBytesList = GetCrlByteList();
    IList<byte[]>? ocspBytesList = GetOcspBytesList();

    Console.WriteLine($"pdf signing manager najed hash interm: {signatureInformation.NakedHashFromIntermediaryPdf.Length}");

    InjectAmaSignatureContainer container = new(signatureInformation.Signature,
                                                _sgn,
                                                signatureInformation.NakedHashFromIntermediaryPdf,
                                                crlBytesList,
                                                ocspBytesList,
                                                _tsaClient);
    PdfSigner.SignDeferred(document, _signatureFieldname, writer, container);
}
```

Finally, `InjectAmaSignatureContainer` is  class which implements the `IExternalSignatureContainer` and that looks like this:

```
public class InjectAmaSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer {
    private readonly IEnumerable<IX509Certificate> _certificates;
    private readonly IEnumerable<byte[]>? _crlBytesCollection;
    private readonly byte[] _documentHash;
    private readonly IEnumerable<byte[]>? _ocspBytes;
    private readonly byte[] _signature;
    private readonly ITSAClient? _tsaClient;
    private readonly PdfSignerHelper _sgn;

    private const string _signaturePolicyUri = "https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/documents/20126/0/POL%2316.PolAssQual_signed_signed.pdf";

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the external container
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="signature">Byte array with AMA's generated signature for specified doc</param>
    /// <param name="certificates">User's certificate chain</param>
    /// <param name="documentHash">Naked document hash used during preparation phase</param>
    /// <param name="crlBytesCollection">CRL information that should be embedded</param>
    /// <param name="ocspBytes">OCSP information that should be embedded</param>
    /// <param name="tsaClient">TSA client that should be used for timestamping the document</param>
    public InjectAmaSignatureContainer(byte[] signature,
                                               PdfSignerHelper sgn,
                                               byte[] documentHash,
                                               IEnumerable<byte[]>? crlBytesCollection,
                                               IEnumerable<byte[]>? ocspBytes,
                                               ITSAClient? tsaClient = null) {
        _signature = signature;
        _sgn = sgn;
        _documentHash = documentHash;
        _crlBytesCollection = crlBytesCollection;
        _ocspBytes = ocspBytes;
        _tsaClient = tsaClient;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Append signature and optional data to the temporary PDF document
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] Sign(Stream data) {
        
        // set the signature bytes
        _sgn.Signer.SetExternalSignatureValue(_signature,
                                      null,
                                      "RSA");
        // call GetEncoded with the same parameters as the original GetAuthenticatedAtt...
        byte[]? encodedSig = _sgn.Signer.GetEncodedPKCS7(_documentHash,
                                                 PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                                                 _tsaClient,
                                                 _ocspBytes?.ToList(),
                                                 _crlBytesCollection?.ToList());

        return encodedSig;
    }

    public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: adding the code for the helper methods `GetCrlByteList` and `GetOcspBytesList` because it seems like there's seomthing wrong with the way I'm getting the info:

```
private IList<byte[]>? GetCrlByteList() => _crlClients == null
                                               ? null
                                               : _userCertificateChain.Select(x509 => GetCrlClientBytesList(x509))
                                                                      .SelectMany(crlBytes => crlBytes)
                                                                      .ToList();

private IList<byte[]>? GetCrlClientBytesList(IX509Certificate certificate) {
    List<byte[]>? crls = _crlClients?.Select(crlClient => crlClient.GetEncoded(certificate, null))
                                    .Where(encoded => encoded != null)
                                    .SelectMany(bytes => bytes)
                                    .ToList();
    return crls;
}

private IList<byte[]>? GetOcspBytesList() {
    if(_userCertificateChain.Count <= 1 || _ocspClient is null) {
        return null;
    }
    IX509Certificate userCert = _userCertificateChain[0];
    IX509Certificate root = _userCertificateChain[1];
    IX509Certificate intermediate = _userCertificateChain[2];
    List<byte[]> list = new();
    byte[]? encoded = _ocspClient.GetEncoded(userCert, intermediate, null);
    if(encoded != null) {
       list.Add(encoded);
    }
    encoded = _ocspClient.GetEncoded(intermediate, root, null);
    if(encoded != null) {
       list.Add(encoded);
    }
    

    return list;
}
```

There's definitely something wrong with the code I'm using because when I don't set the ocsp or clr info, the pdf is considered valid...

This ends up generating the signed pdf, but unfortunately, it gives the previous error. Any clues on what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: ensure you are using the right hashing function for the document, when passing in the `documentHash` to `InjectAmaSignatureContainer`

Comment: Hello. I'm using the same hash (SHA256)...I mean, the code was working with the previous version of itext, the only updates are related with breaking changes and obsolete method calls (everything else is the same)...

Comment: use [this itext7](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet)

Comment: Hello again. Yes, this os a net 8 project, so I'm already using that version...

Comment: Can you share an example PDF signed by your iText 8 based code?

Comment: Hello. Sure. Here it goes: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/uak0mwz458k961172tyr3/doc1_signed.pdf?rlkey=1xcapgwoz1q1cdlsqs1uvol9b&dl=0

btw, one more question: where can we get up to date docs/demos about itext? I had to use it when building the original code and now, that I rewrite it, I'm having a hard time getting up to date code on the docs (seem to be way out of sync)...thanks.

Comment: the [Digital Signatures Hub](https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/digital-signatures-hub) should be a good source of information. Most, if not all of its examples get pulled from the [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signing-examples). Generically speaking, you can also find most up-to-date examples for .NET [on this repo](https://github.com/itext/i7ns-samples/tree/develop/itext/itext.samples). master should contain examples applicable to latest release, and develop applicable to the upcoming release.

Comment: Helllo guys.  Still not working. @mkl, any chance of taking a look at the sample pdf? thanks.

Comment: Re-reading the code in your question I just saw something that would explain the mismatch, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your signature validation problem is that in the embedded CMS signature in the final PDF the signed hash value is not the hash of the authenticated attributes. This happens because you create different authenticated attributes in the first run (from which you calculate the hash to sign) and in the second run (which you put into the final signature container).

They differ in the signature policy attribute and in the adbe-revocationInfoArchival attribute.

## The Signature Policy Attribute

In `PrepareForAmaSigningContainer` you set a policy value of the `PdfPKCS7 sgn` before retrieving the authenticated attributes:

```c#
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new(null,
                   _certificates.ToArray(),
                   DigestAlgorithms.SHA256,
                   false);

// set signature policy information
MemoryStream policyIdByteMs = new(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("2.16.620.2.1.2.2"), false);
byte[]? policyIdByte = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(policyIdByteMs, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);
SignaturePolicyInfo spi = new("2.16.620.2.1.2.2", policyIdByte, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, _signaturePolicyUri);
sgn.SetSignaturePolicy(spi);

// get hash for document bytes
NakedHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);

// get attributes
byte[]? docBytes = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(NakedHash,
                                                      PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                                                      _ocspBytes?.ToList(),
                                                      _crlBytesCollection?.ToList());
```

Thus, the authenticated attributes there *include* a policy attribute and the AMA signature is created for attributes *including* that policy.

But in `InjectAmaSignatureContainer` you create a `PdfPKCS7 sgn` without setting the policy:

```c#
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new(null,
                   _certificates.ToArray(),
                   DigestAlgorithms.SHA256,
                   false);
// set the signature bytes
sgn.SetExternalSignatureValue(_signature,
                              null,
                              "RSA");
// call GetEncoded with the same parameters as the original GetAuthenticatedAtt...
byte[]? encodedSig = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(_documentHash,
                                         PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                                         _tsaClient,
                                         _ocspBytes?.ToList(),
                                         _crlBytesCollection?.ToList());
```

Thus, the encoded CMS container you create there and eventually embed into the PDF has an attribute set *without* a policy entry and a signature value calculated for an attribute set *with* a policy entry. Consequentially, there is a mismatch.

The best option would be to create the `PdfPKCS7` instance only once and to keep and re-use it, so it is guaranteed to be used in an identically initialized form.

If you really need to drop the original `PdfPKCS7` and re-create it later, make sure to re-create it with the identical parametrization. Consider putting that creation and re-creation of the `PdfPKCS7` into a central method you call from both `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementations.

*After fixing this issue you still had a hash value mismatch. As it turned out the OCSP responses in the Adobe revocation information attribute differed in the two runs:*

## The adbe-revocationInfoArchival Attribute

Both in `CreateTemporaryPdfForSigning` and in `SignIntermediatePdf` you call `GetCrlByteList()` and `GetOcspBytesList()` to retrieve the CRLs and OCSP responses respectively.

When you eventually posted the code of these methods, it became clear, though, that these methods may not return the same result in the first call as in the second call:

They both ask the given CRL client and OCSP client respectively for revocation data for the certificates in the signer certificate chain. But these clients are instances of `CrlClientOnline` and `OcspClientBouncyCastle` which collect online the revocation information they are asked for. Thus, the clients may return different information in the first and in the second call.

While for CRLs the chance is pretty low that the online CRL changes in-between those two calls, OCSP responses usually are generated anew for each request. And as OCSP responses contain their generation time (`producedAt`), this means that each `GetOcspBytesList()` call returns a different result.

You, therefore, should call `GetCrlByteList()` and `GetOcspBytesList()` only once when generating a signature, and forward them as `IList` instances to `CreateTemporaryPdfForSigning` and in `SignIntermediatePdf`, so that these methods can embed the same collections of revocation information in the authenticated attributes.

Comment: Hello again. Your explanation makes sense, but I'm under the impression that I've tried it without the policy and it didn't work...I'll refactor the code and let you know how it went tomorrow. thanks again.

Comment: Well, with the current difference in attributes you will definitively get a mismatch. If you still have issues without that difference, please update the code in your question.

Comment: Hello again. still not working (same error). I'm reviewing the post to make sure that all the shown methods are up to date.

Comment: Please also provide a new example signed PDF --- maybe the error message is the same but differences can be found in analysis of the signed file.

Comment: Hello again. The zip file contains all 3 files (original, intermediary and signed): https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/o3h60miaq3zgh0v4hyts1/docs.zip?rlkey=bvzbcetis1t8dq9i24qfoznci&dl=0

Comment: @LuisAbreu Could you please create another such signed example but this time additionally store the contents of the  `MemoryStream hashMemoryStream` and the `byte[] totalHash` in the `PrepareForAmaSigningContainer.Sign` method and share both values, too? In the existing data I only see a mismatch but cannot explain it.

Comment: Hello again. Thanks a lot for your help. I've serialized the contents of the hashmemorystream, docbyteshash and totalhash to 3 dif binary files. Available here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/k4d6mq436o3i63qgivjsl/doc1.zip?rlkey=19ek0xnicp1rhcj9t1vy6i9mg&dl=0

Comment: Hhmmm, this is a bit weird, according to your code `docbyteshash` should hold the hash of the `hashMemoryStream` contents (`docBytesHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(hashMemoryStream, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256);`) but in your binary files they are identical. That cannot be right.

Comment: Also `hashMemoryStream = new(docBytes, false);` should hold the authenticated attributes (`byte[]? docBytes = _sgn.Signer.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(...)`) which they don't do in your binary files.

Comment: @LuisAbreu I just had a look at the question in the course of which you made deferred signing work originally, i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66671008/1729265). There you did not use CRLs or OCSP responses but here you do. As we here have a difference, I wonder whether you for the CRLs and OCSP responses also have made sure that the identical ones are used in `CreateTemporaryPdfForSigning` and in `SignIntermediatePdf`. In other words, do you return the identical results in each `GetCrlByteList()` and `GetOcspBytesList()` call or do you fetch new revocation information each time?

Comment: Hello again @mkl. You're definitely correct: there's something wrong with those methods. they used to work previously, but now they don't. Btw, I've added the code for both of them to my initial post. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, There's something wrong with the ocsp list generation...

Comment: Ok, There's something wrong with the ocsp list (using clr only produces a valid signed pdf). I've noticed that the remote  service that returns the certificate chaing (_certificateChain) stopped returning the chain in order, so I had also to replace the code for the new one that is shown (I'm getting ocsp until the root, 3 certificates, 2 entries). I've updated the estimation code so that it takes the ocsp list into account too. Despite that, still the same error. Updated zip file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/je1r2jrkqbz2d0iuyl49d/doc1.zip?rlkey=b8uty7muwykn2khnzxb36ua8n&dl=0

Comment: @LuisAbreu The problem is simple. Each time `GetOcspBytesList` is called, it requests new OCSP responses for the signer certificate chain. But OCSP responses are freshly created for each request. Thus, you embed different OCSP responses in the first and second run, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. When I migrated from the initial version to the latest releases, I refactor the code (when it was working, the crl and ocsp info was from withinthe constructor of the manager class). I splitted it in 2 because the code must run from a web page and the hash signing process is controlled by pin that is sent to the phone of the user. Btw, I'm assuming that the wrong order chain is something that shouldn't happen right? I mean, the certificate chain returned should be order from user -> intermediary -> root certificate, right?

Comment: *"Btw, I'm assuming that the wrong order chain is something that shouldn't happen right? I mean, the certificate chain returned should be order from user -> intermediary -> root certificate, right?"* - Well, it depends. If they call it a "certificate chain" (or another term implying an order), then indeed I'd also expect the intermediary in the middle. But if they call it "set of certificates from which the chain is built" (or something similar not implying an order), the certificates may come in any order. Defensive programming would require you to check and sort the certificates to a chain.