# Embed a digital signature to a PDF document using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, itext7

The procedure of our digital signing service API is as follows:

1. I request an OTP.
2. I get the OTP from a mail message using IMAP.
3. I send username, password, OTP and the Base64 string of the SHA256 hash of a PDF file.
4. The signing service returns the signature.

The question is: After I get the signature that must be added, how can I embed it into the PDF?

So far I have tried the following code, but it gives a null exception at the line where the signatureField is created. None of the previously declared variables is null, and catch gives no additional info. I used iText7 but any other library that will do the job is OK with me.

```
// Create the PDF reader and writer
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("document.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("document-signed.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

// Create the signature field
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
PdfFormField signatureField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDoc); // <- NULL EXCEPTION
signatureField.SetFieldName("Signature");
form.AddField(signatureField);

// Add the signature text to the field
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 50);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.GetFirstPage()), rect);
canvas.Add(new Paragraph(signature));
signatureField.SetValue("Signature");
signatureField.SetPage(1);
signatureField.GetWidgets()[0].SetRectangle(new PdfArray(rect));

// Close the document
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Your approach is conceptually wrong. Not the original PDF needs to be hashed. Instead you have to prepare the PDF for signing and hash the prepared PDF (except a certain placeholder therein). Read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) for the backgrounds.

Comment: Also, though, there shouldn't be a null exception at the line you indicate? Does that happen for arbitrary source PDFs? Which iText 7 version exactly do you use?

Comment: Concerning your task, what exactly does your signing service API return, a plain signature value or a full-fledged CMS signature container. In the latter case you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168641/1729265). For more backgrounds concerning the iText signing API you may also be interested in [this iText knowledge base article](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signing-with-itext-7).

Comment: Have you by any chance found a solution to this?